# How to apply single β-step at the root

Tags: haskell, lambda

I got the following task:

> Let type Strat = Term -> [Term] be the type of reduction strategies.
> Implement the strategy root :: Strat which applies a single β-step at
> the root (if possible)

Now I know how the different strategies (applicative order reduction, normal order reduction, ...) work.

My question now is, now: Every time I apply a β-step to a term, i get another term. Why should i return a list of terms?

What I have till now is:

```
type Id = String
data Term =     Var Id              -- Var ... variable
                | App Term Term     -- App ... application
                | Abs Id Term       -- Abs ... abstraction
                deriving(Show)

root :: Term -> Term
root (Var v)            = Var v             -- var
root (Abs x s)          = Abs x s           -- abs
root (App (Abs x t) u)  = subst x u t       -- root
root (App s u) = App (root s) (root u)      -- app-l and app-r

-- where subst x s t computes t[x := s], satisfying the freshness constraint.
subst :: String -> Term -> Term -> Term
...(already implemented)
```

**EDIT:**
Maybe I should mention the next two steps, that have to be made, to make the question clear:

> Implement a strategy combinator nested :: Strat -> Strat that, given a
> strategy s, results in a new strategy which tries to apply s at all
> non-root positions.
>
> Building on the previous functions, implement single-step call by name reduction cbn :: Strat.

Comment: If your function should perform a single beta step, I'd suggest to return a `Maybe Term` instead. Return `Nothing` if the input term is in normal form. Return `Just t` if `t` is the next term obtained with a single beta step. In this way you can implement e.g. the leftmost-outermost reduction strategy, since each recursive call will tell you if a step was made or not.

Comment: Having all reductions strategies with the same type makes the subsequent questions involving combinators such as `nested` easier.

Comment: Seems like you @Li-yaoXia now, what to do, can you give me a hint?

Comment: If you need the list return type, you can return `[]` on normal forms, and `[t]` on single beta steps.

Comment: I mean it is no problem to return the term as a list, but what is this helpful for?

Comment: In general, a `Strat` can suggest many alternative steps. E.g., in pseudosyntax, `(f x) (g y)` can be reduced following `f x` or `g y`. A `Strat` can then produce as output `[t1 (g x), (f x) t2]`. Essentially, the output list is used to represent non-deterministic behavior.

Comment: Note that, if you follow the suggestion of @chi, you can turn the output into a list with `unfoldr`.

Comment: Am I right, by thinking, that the intention of the list is, to produce every possible output of any betastep?

Comment: @Soro Yes, that would be the "largest" strategy, modelling the highest level of non determinism. A strategy in general produces a subset of those outputs.